# How to fix ibtool failed with exit code 255 error xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ibtool

Command:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
```

failed with exit code `255`

Getting the above error in xcode `5` I am having both xcode `5` and `6`. I tried all the solutions in google, I uninstalled all xcodes from my mac and reinstalled but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and solved by below steps:

1. Open xib(nib) as Source Code (Right click on the xib Open As >
   TextEdit)
2. Remove this appearanceType="aqua"
3. Save and open using Xcode

Check [this](http://www.tyreeapps.com/blog/tools/2014/06/10/Xcode-Crash-with-xib-Files.html) for further explanation.

Some times it is also solved by Cleaning and Re-building the project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when using xcode 6 (open from .dmg folder), and solved by installing xcode into /Applications directory. It fixed my problem.